# Before search how to hide all sql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my code before searching its showing all user data. What I want is that only after pressing search option, will it show specific user data but before the search, I want to hide all the data. The picture below is my interface

[image: interface of search]

Badly looking for assistance and thanks in advance.

**Here is my code**

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mypro_bms;host=localhost', 'root', '');
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  $q = $_GET['q'];
  $statement = $db->prepare("select * from donate where passport_IC like :passport_IC");
  $statement->execute([
    ':passport_IC' => '%' . $q .'%'

  ]);
} else {
  $statement = $db->prepare('select * from donate');
  $statement->execute();
}
$people = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 ?> 
  <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th><center> id</center></th>
            <th><center> Passport/IC</center></th>
            <th><center> Blood Group</center></th>
            <th><center> Blood Bag Type</center></th>
            <th><center>Donation Date</center></th>
            <th><center>Action</center></th>




          </tr>
          <?php foreach($people as $donors): ?>
            <tr>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->id; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->passport_ic; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_group; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_bag; ?></font></b></center></td>
               <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->donate_date; ?></font></b></center></td>


            </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: If you don't want to show any data before a user makes a search, why not just remove the query in the else-block?

Comment: i did it but after removing the else query my foreach statement showing as invalid argument but if you know how to properly approach then please let me know. thnaks

Comment: That's most likely because you didn't have a correct default value. Check my answer below. That code should work for you and shouldn't give you any "invalid argument" issues.

Comment: For proper approach, you have to read my answer clearly . . . @sayemali

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep this part in seprate file and call this from ajax call.

Keep codes in File search.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><center> id</center></th>
        <th><center> Passport/IC</center></th>
        <th><center> Blood Group</center></th>
        <th><center> Blood Bag Type</center></th>
        <th><center>Donation Date</center></th>
        <th><center>Action</center></th>    
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($people as $donors): ?>
        <tr>
           <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->id; ?></font></b></center></td>
           <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->passport_ic; ?></font></b></center></td>
           <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_group; ?></font></b></center></td>
           <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_bag; ?></font></b></center></td>
           <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->donate_date; ?></font></b></center></td>    
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </table>
```

Keep codes in File fetchsearchresult.php

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mypro_bms;host=localhost', 'root', '');
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  $q = $_GET['q'];
  $statement = $db->prepare("select * from donate where passport_IC like :passport_IC");
  $statement->execute([
    ':passport_IC' => '%' . $q .'%'    
  ]);
} else {
  $statement = $db->prepare('select * from donate');
  $statement->execute();
}
$people = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
// Here you have to pass the data($people) to search.php file
 ?>
```

Now from search.php file, by clicking search button you have to call fetchsearchresult.php through ajax call to get the search result. After getting result you have bind that data in to search.php

**Note: if $_GET['q'] variable didn't get value it'll fetch all detail from table.**

Hope it helps

Comment: _"You have to keep this part in seprate file and call this from ajax call."_ - No, the OP doesn't _have to_ do that. It's an alternative solution, but there's no _"have to"_ here.

Comment: `<font>` and `<center>`, haven't seen those in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to show any data before the user makes a search, you need to remove the else-block:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mypro_bms;host=localhost', 'root', '');

// Default value for the $people array
$people = [];

// We're using empty() to make sure that the search string actually contains something.
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $statement = $db->prepare("select * from donate where passport_IC like :passport_IC");
    $statement->execute([
        ':passport_IC' => '%' . $_GET['q'] .'%'
    ]);

    // We moved this inside of the if-statements
    $people = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
?>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th><center> id</center></th>
        <th><center> Passport/IC</center></th>
        <th><center> Blood Group</center></th>
        <th><center> Blood Bag Type</center></th>
        <th><center>Donation Date</center></th>
        <th><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($people as $donors): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->id; ?></font></b></center></td>
        <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->passport_ic; ?></font></b></center></td>
        <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_group; ?></font></b></center></td>
        <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->blood_bag; ?></font></b></center></td>
        <td><center><b><font color="black"><?= $donors->donate_date; ?></font></b></center></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

This shouldn't give you any errors, since we've created a default value for `$people` and moved the `fetchAll()` to go inside of the if-statement.

Comment: yeah i have tried this one before. but its showing the foreach statement as invalid argument

Comment: @sayemali - Not if you follow the above code to the letter. Note the `$people = [];` in the second row and that we moved the `$people = $statement->fetchAll():` to be inside the if-statement. That should solve the `invalid argument`-issue. If it doesn't, then there's something else in your code you're not showing.

Comment: use this condition `if(!empty($people))` before foreach.

Comment: @RasaMohamed - Since we define `$people = [];` in the top, you shouldn't need to check the variable before the foreach.

Comment: thanks brother you are great. it is working. again many many thanks

Comment: Yes, I didn't read ur comment before I sent mine . . . :-) @ Magnus Eriksson

Comment: @sayemali - Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue. Then others know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, if there is no result found then assigning `$people = []` is waste of memory right instead we can check whether its empty or not

Comment: @RasaMohamed - If you're having memory issues because you create an empty array, you have _way_ bigger issues with your code and/or server. Don't do [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092).